# Asp.net Handler Sending Data

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services

How can i send data to an asp.net ashx handler? for instance if i want to send some xml to asp.net hanlder how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an HttpHandler it's better to make use of a webservice or WCF service instead. However if you want to you can post something to a handler and capture it like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    var xml = context.Request.Form["data"];
}
```

for POST data. For GET data you can use:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    var xml = context.Request.QueryString["data"];
}
```

Or simply:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    var xml = context.Request["data"];
}
```

which'll internally loop over the possible ways of grabbing data.

Comment: how can i send multiple parameters using post method?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, handlers handle HTTP requests and as such they've access to the HttpContext. So you call the handler like 'myhandler.ashx?parameter=value' and then use the HttpContext.Request.QueryString (context.Request.QueryString["parameter"]) to find the value.

Likewise, you can POST data to the handler, add your XML as a POST variable and then use context.Request.Form["myXmlData"]

You can call the handler from any html page:

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="MyHandler.ashx">
        Paste your XML in this textarea:
        <textarea name="MyXmlData" id="MyXmlData" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea><br />
        <button type="submit" value="Call Handler"></button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: the problem is i am trying to call the handler from a rails application. The rails application sends xml data, using webservices is worthless because of the return type. Upon receiving the xml data i want to convert it into a word document at the asp.net server side and then Response back the document.

Comment: tell me some example to POST the data to the handler using asp.net code i can then convert that to rails code.

Comment: I have solved the problem but how can i send multiple values using POST?

Comment: add additional tags to your html, like extra textareas or use the [input type="hidden"]. Give each of them an unique name and id, and you can call them in your handler using the Request.Post["uniqueId"] (of course, replace "uniqueId" with the unique id of the html tag)